# C++ while loop without curly brackets?

Tags: c++

i am studying some code and i notice something i never saw before.

There is a while loop but without the curly brackets.
I should explain what the code does, but this part with the while is confusing me.

I would appreciate it, if someone can explain me why the while loop dont have curly brackets.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <sys/random.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

size_t n_children = 120;          //size_t is an unsigned integer 0 .. 4,294,967,295

typedef int64_t Konto;          // -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 .. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, typedef abkürzung fü int64_t an Konto zugewiesen

Konto konto = 0;                // 64 bits long long

int main() {
  while (fork() && --n_children);   

  unsigned int transaktionen = 100;     // 
  while (transaktionen--) {             // 100 times
    int8_t value;                       //  8 bit signed char (-128 .. 127)
    if (getrandom(&value, sizeof(value), 0) == sizeof(value))
      konto += value;
  }

  cout << "My Konto value: " << konto << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It keeps invoking the `fork()` function until its return value and `n_children` minus one are both positive.

Comment: The body of the loop is `;` - the empty statement. It is equivalent to `{}`.

Comment: @gscaparrotti No, it keeps invoking the function "while" the condition is non-zero, not "until".

Comment: @Markus, you're right, my bad

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of a while loop is `while (<condidtion>) <statement>`

The statement can be a single statement or a compound statement in curly braces.
Here the statement is just `;`, the empty statement.

so this is equivalent to

```
while (fork() && --n_children){}
```

Where the statement is a compound statement, without any other nested statements.
Which is also the form to prefer if all work is done in the controlling condition.

Comment: Ty, i actually didnt know that

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to popular belief, `if`, `while` and `for` can be terminated by a semicolon when it has an empty body and what's sufficient can already be expressed without a body.
For instance, this is an infinite loop:

```
while(1);
```

This is equivalent to

```
while(1) {}
```

In your example:

```
while (fork() && --n_children);
```

This keeps calling the `fork()` function and decrementing `n_children` until at least one of these two expressions evaluate to `0` or `false`. This, of course, is equivalent to:

```
while (fork() && --n_children) {}
```

If either `n_children` becomes 0 or `fork()` returns a falsy value, the loop stops. In other words, both the expressions have to evaluate to `true/1` for the loop to continue and hence the `&&`.

A short example to calculate the length of a C-string using an empty `for` loop:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "A String";
    for(len = 0; str[len] != '\0'; len++);  
    printf("Length: %d", len); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A while loop in C/C++ is defined as:-

```
while condition
   statement or block
```

A block is a series of statements inside a pair of braces. A statement is just a line of code terminated by semi-colon. Statements can be null, or empty, so ';' is a valid statement.
So in this case, the condition in the while loop is repeatedly tested while the contents of the while loop is empty, so it 'spins' on contstantly retesting the condition (in this case, fork'ing). This isn't an ideal pattern, sometimes known as a 'busy wait' loop which will consume lots of CPU time.
In this example, a clearer way to have written it is:-

```
for (int count = 0 ; count < n_children ; ++count)
{
  fork ();
}
```

Older compilers would probably have produced more efficent code but these days the difference would be very marginal.

Comment: Ty, i thought that a while need to have a block with code.

Comment: In the grammar it’s not “statement or block”. It’s simply “statement”. One form of statement is a “compound statement”, which is a pair of curly braces enclosing zero or more statements.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yeah, I know, but the OP doesn't seem that familar with the standard so I was being more explicit about the forms a statement could take to avoid confusion.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that my alternative code won't work, although it looks similar. The while loop should terminate when the fork call returns zero, because it's the child process and you don't want child processes creating sub-processes. It's an odd piece of code that can trip people up easily. Also, it's not very good about handling errors and the parent process doesn't keep a record of the processes it's created so cleaning up could be an issue.

Comment: @Skizz -- defining "statement" incorrectly just sets traps that will be triggered in the future.

Comment: @Skizz Your alternative `for` loop should be: `for(int count = 1; count < n_children && fork(); ++count) { }` or with a body, `for(int count = 1; count < n_children; ++count) { if(!fork()) { break; } }`. Either way, `count` must start from 1 not 0, since the OP uses a pre-decrement operator and the loop iterates only `n-1` times.